# getting error in callout no contant to map due to end of input

Tags: json, callout

I am getting json string error like no contant to map due to end of input

**my webservice**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/v1/contactApi1/*')
global with sharing class ContactResource1 {

    global class ResponseWrapper {
        String success;
        String message;
    }

    // PATCH Method
    @HTTPPatch
    global static List<ResponseWrapper> updateContacts() 
    {
    
        List<ResponseWrapper> responseWrapperList = new List<ResponseWrapper>();
        
        RestRequest contactRequest = RestContext.request;
    
        String requestBody = contactRequest.requestBody.toString();
    
        List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = (List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(requestBody, List<Contact>.class);
    
        Database.SaveResult[] updateResults = Database.update(contactsToUpdate, false);
    
        for(Database.SaveResult updateResult : updateResults) 
        {
        
            ResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper();
        
            if (updateResult.isSuccess()) 
            {
            
                wrapper.success = '1';
                wrapper.message = 'Successfully updated contact with Id: ' + updateResult.getId();
            }
            else 
            {
            
                wrapper.success = '0';
                for(Database.Error error : updateResult.getErrors()) 
                {
                    wrapper.message = 'The following error has occurred for contact with Id: ' + updateResult.getId() + '. ';
                    wrapper.message += error.getStatusCode() + ': ' + error.getMessage() + '. ';
                    wrapper.message += 'Contact fields that affected this error: ' + error.getFields();
                }
            }
        
            responseWrapperList.add(wrapper);
        }
    
        return responseWrapperList;
    }
}
```

**trying to make callout by providing body in the request**

```
public class ContactRource1_calllout {
    public static void fetchmynewapi() {
        http htp = new http();
        HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res= new HttpResponse();
        req.setEndpoint('http://anukiste-developer-edition.ap24.force.com/services/apexrest/api/v1/contactApi1');
        req.setMethod('PATCH');
        req.setBody('[{"id":"0035g000001t4Qn","Leadsource":"online"},{"id":"0035g000001rt5n","Leadsource":"web"}]');       
        res=htp.send(req);
        system.debug('sent request is -->'+req);
        string jsonstr= res.getBody();
        
        system.debug('result in json is -->'+jsonstr);// data coming till here
        responseWrapperCalloutside modelresponse= (responseWrapperCalloutside)json.deserialize(jsonstr, responseWrapperCalloutside.class);
    
        system.debug('final result is -->'+modelresponse);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no compile/run time issues with your `Patch` method or JSON payload. I have validated this. Can you include your `responseWrapperCalloutside` wrapper code too?

Comment: public class responseWrapperCalloutside {
        String success;
        String message;
}

Comment: Can you share what is `jsonstr` value?

Comment: it is showing value as blank

Comment: If there's no JSON, that would explain the error.